# Any method to efficiently compute SVD of a perturbation of matrix $\bf A$ if the SVD of $\bf A$ is already known?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Suppose we know the SVD of matrix $\bf A$, and $\bf B$ is a slight perturbation of $A$ (e.g. $\|{\bf B}-{\bf A}\|_{\text F}$ is relatively small), then is there any method that can efficiently compute the SVD of $\bf B$? That is, can the knowledge of SVD of $\bf A$ be helpful for SVD of $\bf B$?

I searched a little bit and found there are some papers on the bound of perturbation, e.g. [Perturbation Theory for the Singular Value
Decomposition](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/markiwen/Teaching/MTH995/Papers/SVD_Stewart.pdf), but I currently have no luck in finding a method to compute SVD of perturbation taking advantage of the SVD of the original matrix.

Any help or reference will be very much appreciated!

Comment: A good document:(https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_241JS11_chap05.pdf) but which does not address directly your question.

Comment: That depends a bit on what method you like to use for the SVD. If it is an iterative method that only requires matrix multiplication, then you can just perform that method with the initial guess being the SVD of the unperturbed matrix.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01397471) or [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2005.07.021)?

Comment: Cross post [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26929/any-method-to-efficiently-compute-svd-of-a-perturbation-of-matrix-bf-a-if-the), with link to a question with answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X_t = A + (B-A)\times t$ and let $X_t = U_t\Sigma_tV_t'$ be the SVD decomposition of $X_t$. Let $\sigma_{t,i}$ denote $i$-th diagonal element of $\Sigma_t$. Then
$$\dot{\sigma}_{t,i} = (U_t' \dot{X}_t V_t)_{ii}\\ \dot{U}_t = U_tH_t \\ \dot{V}_t = V_tK_t$$
where
$$ H_{t,ij} = \frac{\sigma_{t,j}(U'_t\dot{X}_tV_t)_{ij} + \sigma_{t,i} (U'_t\dot{X}_tV_t)_{ji}}{\sigma_{t,j}^2 - \sigma_{t,i}^2} \\
K_{t,ij} = \frac{\sigma_{t,j}(U'_t\dot{X}_tV)_{ji} + \sigma_{t,i} (U'_t\dot{X}_tV_t)_{ij}}{\sigma_{t,j}^2 - \sigma_{t,i}^2} \\$$
and $H_{t,ii} = K_{t,ii} = 0$, provided that all singular values of $X_t$ are distinct.

Since $\dot{X}_t = B-A$ and $\Sigma_0$, $U_0$, $V_0$ are known, this system of ODE gives $\Sigma_1$, $U_1$, $V_1$, i.e. the SVD decomposition of the matrix $B$. A simple first order approximation can be obtained using the Euler scheme for solving this ODE.

Details an be found in Dieci, L., & Eirola, T. (1999). On smooth decompositions of matrices. SIAM Journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications, 20(3), 800-819.